# Condition for Distance Matrix to be Euclidean

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, graph-theory, euclidean-geometry

Let $D$ be a real symmetric matrix.

Then $D$ is an [Euclidean Distance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance_matrix) if and only if the matrix $M$ defined as either$$ M_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} ( D_{1i}^2 + D_{1j}^2 - D_{ij}^2)$$
or 
$$ M = - \frac{1}{2} (\mathbb{1} - \mathbf{e}\mathbf{s}^T)D^2 (\mathbb{1} - \mathbf{s}\mathbf{e}^T)$$
where $\mathbf{s}^T\mathbf{e} = 1$, $\mathbf{e} = (1,1,1,...,1)$, $D^2 \mathbf{s} \neq 0$ and $D^2$ is the elementwise square of $D$;

is positive semi definite.

## Question

Is there a condition for $D$ to be Euclidean that relies solely on $D$ and not and a matrix derived from it ?

Comment: what is $s$ in your definition of $M$?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh $\mathbf{s}$ is any vector that satisfies the conditions specified below the 2nd equation